# How can/should I kill masscan process

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill, malware

I host a small Ubuntu server with DigitalOcean and recently realized a `guest` user was compromised.  I have been trying to cleanup up my server to stop future attacks and have come across a process that consistently takes up ~25% of my CPU.  The process is running `masscan` and I am under the impression that this process is a result my recent attack.

I have been trying to kill the existing process but a new `masscan` process continues to spawn in its place.  I am first wondering if I am right to assume that this `masscan` process is likely coming from a malicious place and I am then wondering how to go about killing the process for good.

Here is the full command being run:

```
./masscan -p 1835 --banner --rate 50000 --exclude 255.255.255.255 --exclude 10.0.0.0/8 --exclude 192.168.0.0/16 --exclude 127.0.0.0/8 --range 1.0.0.0-223.255.255.255
```

Comment: You may want to delete that instance and rebuild it. See [How do I deal with a compromised server?](//serverfault.com/q/218005)

Comment: @Kusalananda I was trying to avoid that but you may be right

Comment: wiping and rebuilding is the right (and only) answer to a compromised system....but in the short term, you can probably use `pstree` to find the process which is respawning masscan.   also look in the crontab for root and/or the uid running masscan.

Comment: @cas that's lousy advice. any process can fork+exit to get rid of its parent or execute a binary as child of another process by attaching to it with ptrace().

Comment: @UncleBilly I think you mean "accurate" rather than "lousy".  The OP was concerned about masscan respawning after being killed.  That requires some other process to notice that masscan has been killed and respawn it.  Or just run a wrapper script from cron, to start masscan if needed.  This other process **can't** just fork and exit, it has to stick around to restart masscan if/when required.  There are, of course, other methods but detecting and fixing them aren't worth the bother in the short time frame before Doing The Right Thing by wiping and reinstalling.

Comment: @cas Surely, if I had to respawn my garbage on a compromised server, I'll do it via cron, or via some easily identifiable process. Good to know.

Comment: @UncleBilly the perfect is the enemy of the good enough.   my comment was not intended to be a perfect solution to detecting all respawning methods, it was intended to deal with two common respawning methods used by script-kiddie cretins who have no idea what they are doing.    You are, of course, entitled to be a jerk about it - I won't dispute that at all.  It is your fundamental right.